# How do you remove System.Data.OracleClient?

Tags: oracle, gac, odac

I accidently installed `System.Data.OracleClient` 64-bit (ODAC) and used the Oracle Uninstaller to remove the client, then proceeded to install the 32-bit ODAC. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get rid of the 64-bit `System.Data.OracleClient` from the C:\Windows\assembly folder! It keeps on saying that it is in use, even when booting into safe mode. Has anyone ever successfully removed this assembly, and if so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Data.OracleClient` is not part of ODAC, it's part of the .NET Framework and should thus be left alone. ODAC installs the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` and `Oracle.DataAccess.Types` namespaces, and they both live in `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Process Explorer`  from sysinternals ( www.sysinternals.com ) which will tell you which File or which user is using that DLL. Check in services ( `services.msc in Start Menu-> Run` ) and check if all Oracle Services have been uninstalled, if not, stop and disabled them all and then proceed to remove that file.
Untimatelly try to : `gacutil -u dllName.DLL`

from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zykhfde0%28VS.80%29.aspx